# Could Organic systems ever power circuits?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, creature-design, xenobiology, science-in-society

I have a race of mainly insectoid aliens known as the Erepo who have virtually bioengineered a ecosystem around themselves. Now I currently have them using either organic systems they can "grow" or materials those constructs create(ex: metal created spheres secreted by slugs).

Would it be possible to have a organic creature that could generate electricity and then have a way to transfer it to other systems or organisms to power them?

Note: Power generation in the 1000s of joules or if possible a megajoule is what I was thinking this creature could produce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you're asking if you can have a living battery?

Yes, it is not impossible: if you wanted to expand the concept of [organic solar cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organic_solar_cell), you could have your bioconstruct to absorb solar energy to be 'milked' for all purposes. Optimal transfer should work via a direct plugging -even though energy can be moved wireless, there would be a lot of dispertion, not to mention the hazard factor. Instead, if the construct looked like an enormous insect with frontal 'horns' that could be used as plugs, then you can use it to transfer energy safely.

This kind of solution would work just fine for, say, small communities or emergency interventions anywhere near the walking range of the big crawler.

Comment: Should i reword the title? The idea for transferring energy would be  some sort of strand of nerve clusters that you could "plug" into things.

Comment: Sorry, I did read your description, but loose nerve strands to me appear as a little cumbersome. Without an external sheathing, like in cables, they are too vulnerable IMO. The 'plug' would just act like the sheathing you need while the well-protected nerve strads transfer the energy

Comment: The nerves could have a protective layer of skin (preferably hardened). For the heavy duty cables maybe a layer of citin?

Answer (score 5):

You could engineer the [Sodium channels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_channel) in the cells to feed the circuits.

> Sodium channels are integral membrane proteins that form ion channels, conducting sodium ions (Na+) through a cell's plasma membrane.

With (Na+) ions you can build up a difference of potentials, which can be then used to induce a current in a circuit.

In this way you could use the usual metabolism to feed the cells and keep them charged.

Comment: Yes! I get the fun story descriptions of the Erepo feeding their walls and machines.